# Add JS alert to mailto links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, mailto

Is there a way with javascript to automatically have the page look for any mailto links and then have it fire off an alert when a user clicks on the mailto link?

I currently have this:

HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:nachomomma@notyourdomain.com">Email Link</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','mailto',
function() {
alert('This is some alert text');
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Not too sure if I am going about this the correct way or if it's even possible.

Comment: So you have an element `<mailto />`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an actual selector, such as `a[href^="mailto"]`

Comment: So I would need to replace that instead of document?

Comment: change `$(document)` to `$('a[href^="mailto"]')` and `on('click','mailto',` to `on('click',`

Comment: UGH, I'm a goon. I had a typo in my HTML for the mailto link. I had it as maito.

Man...ok, it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @cjd82187 why would you do that, just swap out . $(document).on('click','a[href^="mailto"]' ....

Comment: @cjd82187 no, `$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="mailto"]', function() {})`

Comment: @Mathletics if you do it that way, wont every single click he makes in the document check if the selector is `a[href^="mailto"]`.  It is nice because it can handle items that are dynamically added to the DOM, but if all the mailto links are there at the time the DOM is loaded then its not needed.

Comment: @cjd82187 I think you are over-estimating the performance impact of a document-delegated handler.

Comment: For a single click event, sure its not a big deal, but if you start binding scrolling and other events that are fired often, it could get hairy on an older machine.  I tend to bind events to the object they are intended for, and not the document unless there is a specific reason to.

Answer (score 0):

make like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
              $("a[href^='mailto:']").click(function(){
                          alert('This is some alert text');
                      });
          });
```